# SQL compare aggregated averages (Northwind)

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, having-clause, northwind

My question refers particularly to the Northwind database, therefore I don't provide any reproducible example/data set.

I'd like to select all Products whose UnitPrice is greater than the average UnitPrice for each category, excluding the one Category that the given Product belongs to. I've tried two different approaches, none of which yielded desired results so far.

This one returns an aggregated data set, but I don't know how to (I guess using having by?) compare each UnitPrice with mean unit price for all categories except the one that given Product belongs to

```
select 
p.ProductName, 
UnitPrice, t.mean, t.CategoryID from Products as p
inner join
(select avg(UnitPrice) as mean, CategoryID from Products
group by CategoryID) as t
on p.CategoryID = t.CategoryID
```

Here I was able to compare UnitPrice with the total average of all categories, not excluding the one that the given Product belongs to

```
SELECT x.ProductName, AVG(x.UnitPrice) AS average
FROM Products x
GROUP BY x.CategoryID, x.ProductName
Having AVG(x.UnitPrice)> 
(select AVG(UnitPrice) from Products)
```

The desired results should look like

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You should still provide sample data and expected results so that the question is stand alone. I for one aren't going to obtain a copy of the Northwind database to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could phrase this with a lateral join:

```
select p.*, a.avg_unitprice
from products p
cross apply (
    select avg(p1.unitprice) avg_unitprice
    from products p1
    where p1.categoryid <> p.categoryid
) a
where p.unitprice > a.avg_unitprice
```

This compares the unit price of each product to the average unit price of all products in other categories.

If, on the other hand, you want products whose price is greater than the all averages of other categories, then `not exists` seems like a better fit:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from products p1
    where p1.categoryid <> p.categoryid
    group by p1.categoryid
    having avg(p1.unitprice) >= p.unitprice
)
```

Comment: Thanks, the results look *almost* perfect! Missing only Alice Mutton. Please note that UnitPrice for that Product is 39.00, whereas the average for the category  6 (to which Alice Mutton belongs) is 54.01. That is why our query at the moment filters out this record, because the task is not to compare UnitPrice X with an average for a category to which X belongs, but to compare UnitPrice X with all other average, execpt this particular one

Comment: @Yaahtzeck: I added a `where` clause in the subquery to handle this.